# $.getjson sending parameters by request body not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, getjson

I have an API which sends parameters by request body instead of using URL parameters.
The API working fine by Postman, the screenshot of get request is as follow (my server-side code is in node js):

Postman Get request Screenshot:

[image: Postman Get request Screenshot]

But not working by following java script code, I also used $.ajax but it didn’t work either:

```
$.getJSON('ledger',{"glCode":123,"glName":"Asset"}, function (ledgerDs) {
                console.log(ledgerDs);
            });
```

By using the post method is working fine but because it is actually not a post request, so I mostly prefer using get method.

Comment: Please add complete code, by seeing this, it is difficult to reply

Answer (score 0):

I could use get method by making JSON string object and send it to the server, as you can see in the following code:

```
$.getJSON('ledger/'+JSON.stringify({glCode:123,glName:"Asset"}), function (ledgerDs) {
                console.log(ledgerDs);
            });
```

I could access the parameters in the server-side by the following code:

```
    getLedger:(req,res)=>{
        let paramsObj=JSON.parse(req.params.glParams);
...
    },
```